# Swift Static Array - pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: ios, swift

I have a static array metricsTransactionData in ServiceRequest class. I am invoking multiple request continuously and sometimes I get this error "error for object 0x10b874cb0: pointer being freed was not allocated" on this line  ServiceRequest.metricsTransactionData.append(samp). Pls help

```
public func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didFinishCollecting metrics: URLSessionTaskMetrics) {
    for mem in metrics.transactionMetrics {
        var samp = MetricsData()
        samp.requestDate = mem.requestStartDate
        samp.responseDate = mem.responseEndDate
        samp.url = mem.request.url?.absoluteString
        ServiceRequest.metricsTransactionData.append(samp)
    }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
* thread #3, queue = 'NSOperationQueue 0x6000001edb20 (QOS: UNSPECIFIED)', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x0000000106897b66 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10
    frame #1: 0x00000001068d1080 libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill + 333
    frame #2: 0x0000000106644c45 libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 127
    frame #3: 0x00000001067986e4 libsystem_malloc.dylib`malloc_vreport + 545
    frame #4: 0x00000001067988d5 libsystem_malloc.dylib`malloc_report + 152
    frame #5: 0x00000001049bd910 libswiftCore.dylib`_swift_release_dealloc + 16
    frame #6: 0x0000000104980017 libswiftCore.dylib`assignWithTake value witness for Swift.Array + 23
    frame #7: 0x00000001046f3a5a libswiftCore.dylib`(extension in Swift):Swift._ArrayBufferProtocol._arrayOutOfPlaceUpdate<A where A1: Swift._PointerFunction, A.Element == A1.Element>(inout Swift._ContiguousArrayBuffer<A.Element>, Swift.Int, Swift.Int, A1) -> () + 1146
    frame #8: 0x000000010470aa11 libswiftCore.dylib`Swift.Array._copyToNewBuffer(oldCount: Swift.Int) -> () + 209
    frame #9: 0x000000010470aaf0 libswiftCore.dylib`Swift.Array._makeUniqueAndReserveCapacityIfNotUnique() -> () + 192
    frame #10: 0x000000010470ad98 libswiftCore.dylib`Swift.Array.append(A) -> () + 24
```

Comment: What does the stack look like when the error happens?

Comment: updated with trace

Answer (score 3):

The error tells you that it is a very bad idea to use a static/global array that will be updated from various background tasks. Swift arrays are not thread-safe.

Means that your array gets resized by one task while another might already do the same, resulting in a bad memory access. Likely calling (at least) append in a DispatchQueue.main.async would fix the problem if you really have to do it that way, but if you want to maintain the order, you would need to handle synchronization yourself.

But in any way i strongly recommend that you find another solution that prevents that kind of write access to the array directly. Globally writable arrays are bad.